# Text syntax inside a "insset else" code which is inside "echo"

Tags: php, syntax, echo, isset

I have this code:

```
echo ('<div></div>
'.(isset($replay->extra['mode']) ? $replay->extra['mode'] : "n/a").' 
<div></div>')
```

I want to put the this text before the just $replay->extra['mode'] : "n/a").'

```
M-
```

so that it will look like this:

```
M-$replay->extra['mode'] : "n/a").'
```

to be fully like this:

```
 echo ('<div></div>
    '.(isset($replay->extra['mode']) ? M-$replay->extra['mode'] : "n/a").' 
    <div></div>')
```

But i keep getting **syntax error** so what is the correct syntax and way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string within the inline `if` statement by making it a string (enclose in quotes) and using a `.`.

```
echo ('<div></div>'.(isset($replay->extra['mode']) ? 'M-' . $replay->extra['mode'] : "n/a").'<div></div>')
```

You may also have an error with your `<div></div>`'s - unless you are trying to create an empty `<div>` before and after your string, you likely the following to wrap your output with the `<div>` tags:

```
echo ('<div>'.(isset($replay->extra['mode']) ? 'M-' . $replay->extra['mode'] : "n/a").'</div>')
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I left those DIVs as an example as there are alot of other text and html stuff in the original full code which is too long to be copied.